# Django Add default value to model field having the value of another field

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a field to my django model and I want its default value to be equal to the primarykey value (id), but I want it to apply to all already existing records in my database.

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
  id= models.IntegerField()
  index = models.IntegerField(default=" i want something here to get id value")
```

I found previous questions covering this but the answers only give a solution where you have to add a method that adds the value on save. In my case I want this value to be applied to previously saved records also.

Please if you have an idea I'd appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Why not make it a NULLable field (`null=True`) and work with a property such that if it is NULL, it returns the value for the `id`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please elaborate? will the property be applied at migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preform this step by overriding the save method. You can also create a function that updates all the past models.

models.py

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField()
  index = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.index:
      self.index = self.id
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

To create a 'refresh' function, try this:

admin.py

```
...
from .models import ModelB

def refresh_objects(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for object in queryset:
        object.save()

refresh_objects.short_description = "Update selected objects."

class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [refresh_objects]

admin.site.register(ModelB, ModelBAdmin)
```

Now, simply head to the admin site, select all the models to refresh, and run this action. (It can be found in the dropdown)